# Empty answer from webclient C#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webclient

I'm trying to receive data from compressor, but it's answer is always empty. Here is my code:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType]= "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
string question = "online_pressure"; 
string URL = "http://10.0.163.51/getVar.cgi"; 
string answer = client.UploadString(URL, "POST", question);
Console.WriteLine(answer);
```

When I use this code for another compressor, which different only 2 strings, it works great and I can see answer in console:

```
string question = "QUESTION=300201"; 
string URL = "http://10.0.163.50/cgi-bin/mkv.cgi";
```

Code in VBS works great for both compressors. I can see answer in MsgBox from first and second compressors:

```
Dim objHTTP
strToSend = "online_pressure"
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
Call objHTTP.Open("POST", "http://10.0.163.51/getVar.cgi", false)
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHTTP.Send strToSend
MsgBox(objHTTP.ResponseText)
```

HttpRequest code works just for second compressor too:

```
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;
    StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
    requestWriter.Write(data);
    requestWriter.Close();

    try
    {
        // get the response
        WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();
        Stream webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream);
        string response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        responseReader.Close();
        Console.WriteLine(response);
    }
    catch (WebException we)
    {
        string webExceptionMessage = we.Message;
    }
```

What I can try else to get data from first compressor in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebClient and HttpWebRequest still do not works with this comressor. I tried to add any headers, but no result.

I tried PowerShell and it returns empty response too:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://10.0.163.51/getVar.cgi -Method POST -Body "package_discharge_pressure" -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

Curl not working too, it hangs without errors

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "sump_pressure" http://10.0.163.51/getVar.cgi
```

Javascript and VBS works good. And today I found c# code wich works too

```
WinHttpRequest req = new WinHttpRequest();
try {
    req.Open("POST", "http://10.0.163.51/getVar.cgi", true);
    req.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    req.Send("sump_pressure");
    req.WaitForResponse();
}
catch(Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine("Error : " + ex.Message.Trim());
}
Console.WriteLine(req.ResponseText);
```

In visual studio need to make reference to WinHttp

Answer (score 1):

I compared the three requests in Fiddler 4 and realized that the only difference (apart from some other headers which won't affect behavior) between vbs script and both WebClient 
 and HttpWebRequest is that, managed API's send the `Expect: 100-continue` header and vbs script does not.

This can be the issue if the software running on the compressor device does not support this.

Please try the following, which tells the HttpWebRequest to not send this header:

For the HttpWebRequest, you can simply prevent sending this by:

```
 request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
```

Note: For the WebClient, the assignment requires accessing to the HttpWebRequest object used internally, but this has "protected" access modifier and can be worked around.

Before setting this value:

```
POST http://oguzozgul.com.tr/getVar.cgi HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: oguzozgul.com.tr
Content-Length: 15
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

online_pressure
```

After setting this value:

```
POST http://oguzozgul.com.tr/getVar.cgi HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: oguzozgul.com.tr
Content-Length: 15
Connection: Keep-Alive

online_pressure
```

I also want to put the vb script request here so you can see other differences as well. The Accept-Encoding and some other headers are also not sent by default:

```
POST http://oguzozgul.com.tr/getVar.cgi HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Language: tr,en-US;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7,en;q=0.5,zh-Hans-CN;q=0.3,zh-Hans;q=0.2
UA-CPU: AMD64
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; wbx 1.0.0; Zoom 3.6.0; wbxapp 1.0.0)
Host: oguzozgul.com.tr
Content-Length: 15
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

online_pressure
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I added this code after WebClient, and before, but it is not working still... And I not uderstand about "You should get a backup of the existing value, query the compressor and set it back."  Did you mean after query insert ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true; ?

Comment: I am sorry to hear that. Yes, setting it back to true if it had been true before we changed it is what I meant

Comment: I think you should compare the headers sent. Problem must be there, user-agent may be. It is not sent by default ( should not be a problem though, but can be given a try )

Comment: Set `[HttpWebRequest].ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;`, to the current request ServicePoint instead of the general settings of the ServicePointManager. Add a `User-Agent` header and `[HttpWebRequest].Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "no-cache");` See the HttpStatusCode if it fails.